# Angular2 - Same Component Referenced Twice

Tags: angular

Let's say you have the same component displaying two different sets of data based on a filter:

```
<movie-list #future></movie-list>
<movie-list #past></movie-list>
```

Is there a way to derive on the movie-list component whether methods are being called from #future or #past?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that. You could pass an argument to the function that indicates that.

```
<movie-list #future></movie-list>
<movie-list #past (click)="future.doSomething('past')"></movie-list>
```

Comment: I think in click event it should be `future.doSomething('past')` instead of using `#future`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!